# Particular layout above Soft Keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-softkeyboard

I have a layout, code below

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_question"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/white" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!--some stuff here-->

    </LineaLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!--some stuff here-->

    </LineaLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

In the above layout, when the keyboard gets visible, I want layout ll_1 to go above soft keyboard but layout ll_2 shouldn't.

Comment: Is `ll_1` in same file with `ll_2`?

Comment: Yes, the xml I have provided is a single file.

Comment: I think you can't, since android just only allows we few options for ways of showing softkeyboard by modifying value of `android:windowSoftInputMode`, which effects whole layout in same Activity instead of small specific layout in that big layout hold by Activity. There is a [blogs](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html) that may help you understand more soft keyboard and its options.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `Relativelayout` instead of `Linearlayout`?
Like this.

```
<Relativelayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--If it is at the top. If not, delete the alignParentTop feature.-->
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_question"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
        android:background="@color/white" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/et_question"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!--some stuff here-->

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!--If it is at the top. If not,delete the alignParentBottom feature.-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ll_1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!--some stuff here-->

    </RelativeLayout>

</Relativelayout>
```

If you don't mind, firstly try using `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` on `ll_2`.